# required key not available when starting docker container

Tags: docker, authorization

I am trying to start a container pulled from aws with

`docker volume create my_volume`

`docker run -v ~/my/dir:/vol/directory --mount source=my_volume,target=/volume -it --privileged aws.location.com/myrepo`

but most times I am getting a Required key not available error when docker tries to copy my local files to the container (sometimes however it works without any issues).
I do not think my local directory is encrypted and running with sudo also does not solve the problem.

does anyone have any ideas on what the issue could be or how to better diagnose it?

Comment: Unsure but a couple of suggestions: try a generic container (perhaps `busybox`) instead of your container and see whether that makes a difference; drop `--privileged`, I think you should not need to add this; `~` is better replaced with e.g. `${PWD}` or `$(pwd)` to ensure the absolute path reference. Please add more details to your question, perhaps including the `docker cp` command and the error details

Comment: the exact error I get changes from simply

```/bin/bash: /vol/directory/container_setup_script.sh: Required key not available```

without any more information, to a full log of the setup script with a lot of errors like this one:

```sudo -kS cp -r /vol/directory/example/directory
[sudo] password for docker: cp: cannot open '/vol/directory/example/directory/example_script.py' for reading: Required key not available```

Comment: I Googled `Required key not available` when run from a bash script and this appears to result if you're trying to load kernel modules. If correct, I think you cannot load kernel modules from within a container. Containers depend on the kernel and it seems (not certain) to be reasonable that you can't tweak the kernel from a container